# I want to use an object to help create a chart with Chartjs

Tags: javascript, object, chart.js, object-literal

```
class HeartGraph {
    constructor(label, data, backgroundColor, borderColor, fill) {
        this.label = label;
        this.data = data;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.borderColor = borderColor;
        this.fill = fill;
    }
    
    getGraph() {
        var graph = {
            "label" : this.label,
            "data" : this.data,
            "backgroundColor" : this.backgroundColor,
            "borderColor" : this.borderColor,
            "fill" : this.fill
        };
        return graph;
    }
}

var systolic_graph = new HeartGraph(
    'Systolic', 
    <?php echo(json_encode($systolic)); ?>,
    "rgba(60, 111, 194, 1)",
    "rgba(60, 111, 194, 1)",
    false
);
```

// PRINT THE RESULTS OF RETURNING THE OBJECT TO THE CONSOLE

```
console.log(systolic_graph.getGraph());
```

// FROM WITHIN THE DATASETS PARAMETER OF THE CHART() CALL, INSTEAD OF THIS:

```
{
    label: 'Diastolic',
    data: <?php echo(json_encode($diastolic)); ?>,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(76, 245, 112, 1)",
    borderColor: "rgba(76, 245, 112, 1)",
    fill: false
}
```

// I WANTED TO SIMPLY USE:

```
{
    systolic_graph.getGraph()
}
```

Why won't this work?  The console in Chrome tells me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'" and the line it references points to --> systolic_graph.getGraph()

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out! Chartjs expects object literals (ie, { ..... }), but I was returning an object literal along with its curly braces, inside of a { } container.  So, it ended up looking something like this:

```
{
    {
    label: 'Diastolic',
    data: <?php echo(json_encode($diastolic)); ?>,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(76, 245, 112, 1)",
    borderColor: "rgba(76, 245, 112, 1)",
    fill: false
    }
}
```

Those outer curly braces can't be there.  I think I understand this correctly.  :)